# Android drop-down 'command' menu

Tags: android, android-widget

I'd like to use a drop-down menu for letting the user choose an action (in this case, they select some items from a list, and use the menu to select "delete", "move" etc.)

The way Spinner works is quite close to what I want, except Spinner is clearly designed for selecting some data, rather than issuing a command.

- Before it is clicked, I'd like the drop-down menu to just look like an arrow (no adjacent space for displaying the 'currently selected' data
- Ideally the drop-down menu would appear directly beneath the arrow, rather than in the middle of the screen.
- Items in the menu shouldn't have a radio button to indicate whether they are selected

Is there a component that is more appropriate for this than Spinner, or should I achieve these goals by tweaking a Spinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [ContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html) to do what you are looking for. In the dev guide there is a [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) about menus and a section about ContextMenus that will help with the implementation. If you put some time in skinning this menu you can change the look to match what you want.

Answer (score 0):

may be i not getting you but You can use **actionsheet** which you can handle as you want